# How I use dynamic routes with subfolders?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, routes

I am having file structure like this:

```
├── books
    ├── reviews
        ├── [title].jsx <- want to route here 
│   └── page.jsx
└── page.jsx
```

On the /books page I generate a list of books, each of it it's has it's own button to redirect to the review page of this book. For example books/reviews/nextjsbook

When I try to open any review page using: */books/reviews/[title]* I get 404 error.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are using latest next.js 13 App router version
You Should update your folder structure like this

```
├── books
    ├── reviews
        ├── [title]
            ├──page.jsx
│   └── page.jsx
└── page.jsx
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

When you try to navigate to this route directly (i.e., by entering the URL in the browser), It will not be able to find the file because it's looking for a file named `[title].jsx` inside the `reviews` directory. This is why you're getting a **404** error.

Therefore, I suggest to use the `Link` component from `next/link` for navigation and the `useRouter` hook from `next/router` to access the dynamic route parameter.

Example:

```
import Link from 'next/link';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router';

export default function BookList({ books }) {
 const router = useRouter();

 return (
   <div>
     {books.map((book) => (
       <Link href={`/books/reviews/${book.title}`} key={book.title}>
         <a>{book.title}</a>
       </Link>
     ))}

     {router.query.title && (
       <div>
         <h1>{router.query.title}</h1>
         <p>This is the review page for {router.query.title}.</p>
       </div>
     )}
   </div>
 );
}
```

`Link` is used to create a link to the review page for each book. Then, the `href` prop is set to the path for the review page, and the book title is included as a dynamic segment.

The `useRouter` hook is used to access the dynamic route parameter if the `title` query parameter is present in the URL, a div is rendered with the title and a message.